# MVC Model restricted values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How do I restrict ApplicationType to certain values, only A,B,C,D?
in the MVC Model?

```
public partial class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationType;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Add a `[RegularExpression]` attribute. Or make `ApplicationType` and enum containing only those values

Comment: This is precisely what enums are for.

Comment: thanks, how would I modify [RegularExpression] to allow only A or B or C or D? RegularExpression("A,B,C,D"), sorry, extremely new here

Comment: ok, will look at enumerations also

Comment: The easiest way is just using enum instead of `RegularExpressionAttribute`. If you want to use regex, just add `[A-D]` or `[a-d]` condition depending which kind of values you want to allow with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RegularExpression` attribute:

```
[RegularExpression("[^A-z][A,B,C]")] 
public string ApplicationType { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an enum, enums are the best suite for this scenario.make 
ApplicationType an enum and it will work as expected.